# Running code in the background and validating the thread

Tags: android, multithreading

I've been trying for hours to figure this one out and have tried various techniques but can't seem to get a task running in the background. I got this code in my `OnClickListener`:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
     public void run() {
          //doing some work in the background here
          Log.d(tag, "Thread: " + checkThread());
     }
}).start();
```

And within the thread, I'm checking if the code was executed on the main/UI thread or background. So I've got this:

```
private String checkThread() {
    if (Looper.getMainLooper().getThread() == Thread.currentThread()) {
        return "Main";
    } else {
        return "Background";
    }
}
```

But the above always returns "Main". I've tried `Handler`, `AsyncTask` etc. but all of them return the same thing.

Any pointers on how I could get my code to run in the background and also be able to see it in the log that it's not running in the main thread?

Comment: use https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html 
sticky service will help you it runs o background even if you force close your application

Comment: I copy/pasted exactly your code and it returns me `D/MainActivity: Thread: Background`

Comment: Should have mentioned that I'm running Retrofit 2 callback in the background thread and calling `checkThread()` in `onResponse`

Comment: `onResponse` is a callback interface, triggered in current main UI thread, so yes, it can't be on background thread and always returns `Main`

Comment: Is there any way to get the `onResponse` in the background too? As I'm trying to avoid UI thread locking, would it be a good idea to start a new thread from the response?

Comment: I don't think so, it's a callback from a background thread to a current thread, so you'll have to change Retrofit directly or yes, adding a new thread. I don't know what you want to achieve, but you could add to a View queue what you need to do, as `view.post(new Runnable() { ... });` for example ([#2 in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24035591/2668136)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is you have to specify the type of thread priority with `setThreadPriority`. Try as follows:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
     public void run() {
         // moves the current Thread into the background
         android.os.Process.setThreadPriority(
                        android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);

         // doing some work in the background here
         Log.d(tag, "Thread: " + checkThread());
     }
}).start();
```

This should be return `background`.